# Dereferencing the void pointer in C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a generic linked list. The struct for the node is as follows -

```
typedef struct node{
        void *data;
        node *next;      
};
```

Now, when I try to assign an address to the data, suppose for example for an int, like -

```
int n1=6;
node *temp;
temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
temp->data=&n1;
```

How can I get the value of n1 from the node? If I say -

```
cout<<(*(temp->data));
```

I get -

```
`void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
```

Doesn't void pointer get typecasted to int pointer type when I assign an address of int to it?

Comment: Why are you using malloc and C-style pointers in a C++ program ?

Comment: if this is not an exercise, stop reinventing the wheel and use e.g. linked list provided in [glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.32/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html)

Comment: @PaulRL The OP mentions C as the language of implementation in his question title.

Comment: Can we please keep cout/printf out of question here? It's just about dereferencing void pointer and yes its an exercise.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: True. That is what should be pointed out then. Using `malloc` in C++ is just fine. This trend of looking down on `malloc` and `free` in C++ has become sort of a style statement that I don't agree with.

Comment: If you want to make your linked list truly generic then you should use templates. If you want each of your node to point to different object (thru data pointer), then you might want to implement some kind of Variant functionality, ie. add integer field that will contain additional information on the type of data, you will use it for casting, or use Boost/Any

Comment: Ok, then ignore my comment, as a comparison to C++ you might want to take a look at that glib code to get an idea how generic storage types have been implemented in C.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must first typecast the `void*` to actual valid type of pointer (e.g `int*`) to tell the compiler how much memory you are expecting to dereference.

Comment: So, in this case of generic linked list, each node has a different type of data like int or char or char*. So, to get the value of each data I need to typecast? That means I can't loop over the linked list and get the data values in a generic way?

Comment: You need to either typecast (knowing the underlying type) or create a generic container that knows the underlying type and can properly return its value.

Comment: @theharshest, for generic linked list you should be using templatized constructs, e.g. `std::list`

Comment: If nodes of the same list do not share a common type you are probably going to have to "box" them (make their values be held by specialized classes derived from a base one).

Answer (score 4):

A void pointer cannot be de-referenced. You need to cast it to a suitable non-void pointer type. In this case, `int*`

```
cout << *static_cast<int*>(temp->data);
```

Since this is C++ you should be using C++ casts rather than C styles casts. And you should not be using `malloc` in C++, etc. etc.

Comment: ...and if you're writing a 'generic' linked list you should be using generics.  Or as we call them, templates.  :-)

Comment: I wonder why this answer and the accepted answer have downvotes.

Comment: I think it might be because even though you answered the question perfectly correctly as it was asked, using that answer would still end up with bloody awful code!  :-)

Comment: @user That could explain upvotes to other answers. Downvoting answers that address the question as asked is just bizarre in my view.

Comment: I could imagine a down vote or two from "should be using C++ casts rather than C style". Seeing as how it ultimately matters little and has even less to do with the question. Just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

A void pointer cannot be dereferenced. You need to cast it to a suitable non-void pointer type. The question is about C++ so I suggest considering using templates to achieve your goal:

```
template <typename T> struct node
{
   T *data;
   node<T> *next;      
};
```

then:

```
int n1=6;
node<int> *temp = new node<int>();
temp->data=&n1;
```

And finally:

```
cout << (*(temp->data));
```

Typecasting is possible, but that will be a C-style type-unsafe solution and not a C++ one.

Comment: The `typedef` is unnecessary in C++, and since we are taking templates... Also, it seems rather useless to have data be `T*`, a simple `T` would suffice.

Comment: Fixed. T* is used as provided by the original author.

Comment: Also, use `std::unique_ptr<node<T>> next;` (or preferably `boost::optional<node<T>> next;`) instead. And the first node need not be dynamically allocated; just use `node<int> temp;`.

Comment: @SergeyK.: I disagree. The OP does not use `T*`, he uses `void*`. The important difference is that polymorphism requires indirection (an issue of size), but with parametric code there is no longer any polymorphism necessary. Therefore `T` is a viable substitution.

Comment: In case of T you have to store a copy (value), in case of T* the value can be shared. Though, it does not matter for integral types.

Comment: I'd store data as `T`, and let the user of the class decide whether to store pointers or objects.

Answer (score 0):

Typecast temp->data to int and then print.

```
cout<<*((int *)temp->data);
```